# Vertical tabs using CSS3 transform:rotate attribute positioning difficulties

Tags: css, tabs, rotation, transform

Ive set up a testing FIDDLE with all the tools we need for tabs working horizontally.

The classes also exist to allow the tabs to work vertically on either the left hand or right hands side using different CSS classes. The problem is they are not then positioned correctly. This I imagine is due to the transform origin attribute but I am struggling.

http://jsfiddle.net/H7gG8/19/

```
.tabs {
    width:400px; height:400px;
}
.tab { 
    position:relative;
}
.tab li {
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0; height:40px; width:110px; background:#DDD; float:left; cursor:pointer;
} 
.tab.v {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
.tab li.l {
    width:180px;
}
.tab.r {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
.tab.r li {
    float:right;
}
.tabs .conts {
   height:100%; position:relative; clear:both;
}
.tabs .cont {
    background:#EEE; height:300px; position:absolute; width:100%;
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the height attribute of the tab container to that of the entire tab framework ie. height:100%; add a top:-40px to the container and then for vertical tabs add right:0 and top:0;

http://jsfiddle.net/H7gG8/71/

Simples..